# Storing static copies of jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

I have some elements with a certain class and I want to store them in a variable when the document loads, like:

```
$(function(){
    var sliderElements = $('.slider-element');
});
```

The problem is that I want a static copy of those elements (as in, the original elements should still exist in `sliderElements` even if I delete them from the document in the meantime).
I've tried using `clone()` and it doesn't seem to work in any version of Internet Explorer.

Could you please recommend me a workaround?

Comment: So you're saying the descendants of the `.slider-element` elements should be static? Then your `.clone()` solution should work. What did IE do incorrectly?

Comment: It just doesn't behave like they've been cloned and keeps manipulating them dynamically in the DOM.

Comment: I think you are facing a scope issue with your variable sliderElements. Could you provide a jsfiddle?!

Comment: @Cristi how did you use `.clone()` ?

Comment: @Spokey basically `var sliderElements = $('.slider-element').clone()`

Comment: But here sliderElements will be a local variable, are you aware of it?

Comment: @roasted Yes, but the rest of my code is present within the same `$(function(){...})` so there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: @Cristi That's ok then, that was what i want to know ;) BTW, what is the rest of your code relevant to your issue?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using, and what version(s) of IE did you test? ...also, what type(s) of elements are being cloned?

Comment: @roasted Basically, I bind a function on a click event that removes all .slider-element elements from the DOM and adds some filtered ones from sliderElements back.    I have to do it like this because the project is not entirely mine and there are many things that break very easily if I tried to do it with stuff like `display: none`.

Comment: And of course to remove all of them from the DOM you are using: `$('.slider-element').remove()`  correct?  I'm unable to reproduce what seems to be your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/nhwUQ/

Comment: @roasted Damn, yes. I really have no clue why this is happens, but thanks for wasting your time with me man, I'll try to figure it out tomorrow when I have a clear mind.

Comment: @Cristi it's your code that is removing them and then "adds some filtered ones back"? Why not just only remove the ones that don't match your filter? Then you don't need to worry about clone, holding on to references, etc..  or is there more to this? This is the type of problem where I'd try to avoid the need to hold the reference or do the clone .. come at it from a different angle.