# How to make copies of jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I am working on something that allows the user to alter an svg file based on input, such as text, bold, italic, ect. Then, I want the user to be able to revert to the original template without having to reload the file again.

I essentially want a copy of the object.

**What I've tried**

```
// Get template
$.get('../path/to/file.svg', function(svg_template)
{
    var svg = svg_template.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

    // Alter template
    $('#bold').click( function() {
        svg.text.attr('font-weight', 'bold');
    });

    // Return to original template
    $('#reset').click( function() {
        var svg = svg_template.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    });

}, 'xml');
```

And I've tried this in many variations.

```
var svg = svg_template.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svgcopy = svg_template.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

// ...

$('#reset').click( function() {
    svg = svg = svg_copy;
});
```

I've also read up on something in jQuery called `extend()`, but I'm getting "Illegal invocation"

```
var svg = svg_template.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svg_copy = jQuery.extend(true, {}, svg);

// ...

$('#reset').click( function() {
    svg = svg = svg_copy;
});
```

I've also looked at `clone()`, however that requires a copy of it exists in the DOM, which is much slower, requires me to hide the object, and select the object from the Dom when I need it, and even still, how do I select it without making yet another clone of it, because placing a variable equal to the clone puts me in the same position I started in.

Only relevant question I could find is unanswered.

[Storing static copies of jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836418/storing-static-copies-of-jquery-objects)

**Behavior I get**

Instead of a copy, each time I make a variable equal to that object, it acts as a pointer to it, a representative of that object, and any alteration to one one object affects other variables that are also equal to that object.

**My question**

How can I make a copy of a jQuery object?

Comment: take a look at `clone()` in API

Comment: I have and it isn't right for what I'm looking for, I'll update my question with that. Firstly, as I've read, only works if you make a physical copy of it in the Dom. You can't have a virtual copy, which is ideal. Second, that requires me to hide it, and to select it from the Dom. I suppose it is possible, but I imagine there must be a way to have a purely virtual copy of this object without Dom manipulation. Also, I can't set a variable equal to the cloned object, because it will be a pointer, and then I'm back where I started. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: You can clone a clone and you can also wrap the response in `$()` so it doesn't have to be in the dom

Comment: I need to do this hundreds of times. Won't this create hundreds of clones. Please post an answer if you believe you have a valid solution. It would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Kogicon's answer did not work, it did inspire my solution, which I'm posting here for anyone else who faces this issue. I serialized the object, and then unserialize it whenever I need a copy of it. This is quick and simple to understand. Credit goes to Kogicon.

```
$.get(template_path, function(svg_template)
{ 
  var svg_original = svg_template.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]; 
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
  var svg_copy = serializer.serializeToString(svg_original); 
  var svg = $.parseXML(svg_copy); svg = $.parseXML(svg_copy); 
  svg = svg.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];}, 'xml');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to save the data in an element, I would suggest using `var svg = $('svg');` to select the svg, then using the `var svg_save = svg.html();` to get all of the innerHTML as a string. Then you can reset by using `svg.html(svg_save);`. Hope it helps!

Comment: After doing `var svg_save = svg.html();`, svg_save is equal to undefined. I'm not sure html() is the right tool, but I like the idea of storing it in a string so it has to be it's own copy. Please see if you can get this idea working. I will try myself.

Comment: I found a solution inspired by your attempt. If your incorporate this into your answer, I will accept it gladly. `$.get(template_path, function(svg_template){
var svg_original = svg_template.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]; var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); var svg_copy = serializer.serializeToString(svg_original); var svg = $.parseXML(svg_copy); svg = $.parseXML(svg_copy); svg = svg.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];}, 'xml');`